# Convert an address into a ContractContainer in Brownie

Tags: python, brownie

I have a factory contract, that in a transaction:

- Deploys a contract
- Emits an event with the address of the contract it deployed

I want to be able to use the address returned to interface with the contract that was deployed.
EX:

```
from brownie import AstroSwapExchange, AstroSwapFactory
[...]
tokenExchangeAddress = forgeTx.events["TokenExchangeAdded"][0]["tokenExchange"]
return tokenExchangeAddress

tokenExchangeAddress = deploy_new_exchange(factory, erc20)
CREATE A CONTRACT OBJECT HERE
factory = exchange.factory()
```

What functions could I use to take advantage of the returned address and turn it into a Contract object to interact with it like any other contract that I deploy myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer myself! (Not sure if it's the best thing to do but here's how)

Step 1: Get the ABI for the contract you want to create a source of. In my case, it was a contract that was importable through brownie so:

```
from brownie import AstroSwapExchange, AstroSwapFactory
[...]
exchangeAbi = AstroSwapExchange.abi
```

Step 2: Use Contract.from_abi to create the contract. The part that confused me in the documentation is that you need to use the contract from `brownie.network.contract` instead of the actual ContractContainer from `brownie`.

```
from brownie.network.contract import Contract
[...]
exchange = Contract.from_abi("AstroSwapExchange", exchangeAddress, exchangeAbi)
```

And there we go! A `Contract` variable we can use to interface with things like:

```
tokenExchangeFee = exchange.feeAmmount()
```

Comment: You got it! For clarity, I think that returns a `Contract` object rather than a `ContractContainer`. If that's what you want, could you update your question? https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html?highlight=from_abi#contract-classmethods

Comment: @PatrickCollins Quite true, updated.

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner and simpler approach is use the `ContractContainer.at(<address>)`.

The compiled project contracts that you import from `brownie` are of the `ContractContainer` type. Thus, in your example, both `AstroSwapExchange` and `AstroSwapFactory` are instances of the `ContractContainer` type. As such, your code can be simplified to the following:

```py
from brownie.network.contract import ProjectContract
from brownie import AstroSwapExchange

exchange: ProjectContract = AstroSwapExchange.at(exchangeAddress)
```

References:

- [ContractContainer.at() documentation](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api-network.html#ContractContainer.at)